# Recursion - how do you extract from specific traversals

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

Lets say you have a string: abcde

And a set of strings: ab, cde, abcd, a, bcd, cd

You want to find all possible concatenations from the set that form the string.

You can use recursion to traverse through all possible concatenations from the set, but how would you return only those that satisfy the solution?

The possible combinations:

```
ab - cde - yes
ab - cd - no
abcd - no
a - bcd - no
ab - cd - no
```

You can build a tree from the traverse and then extract the paths that complete. Is there a way without using a tree?

I am implementing this in Python but feel free to answer in any language.

Comment: Your list of "possible combinations" is not exhaustive, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's not exhaustive, but making guesses based on the string.

Comment: Is this homework? It doesn't seem like a real world problem.

Comment: It's a real world problem. I am working on converting pinyin with diacriticals to pinyin without. It's not for work, but a side project. I posted the problem in reductio to make things simpler. I already have a solution - the tree, but am looking for something more elegant. I wish I were still in school.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to structure the search as a generator. In python, it might look like this:

```
def concatenations(target_string, fragments, concat_path=()):
    if not target_string:
        yield concat_path
    else:
        for frag in fragments:
            if target_string.startswith(frag):
                new_target = target_string[len(frag):]
                new_path = concat_path + (frag,)
                for c in concatenations(new_target, fragments, new_path):
                    yield c
```

Note that I have assumed that the elements from the set can occur more than once in the string. If that is inappropriate, replace `fragments` by `fragments - {frag}` in the recursive call.

You can get all elements by just gathering all the results from the generator into a list:

```
fragments = {"ab", "cde", "abcd", "a", "bcd", "cd", "e"}
list(concatenations("abcde", fragments))
```

This produces:

```
[('a', 'bcd', 'e'), ('abcd', 'e'), ('ab', 'cde'), ('ab', 'cd', 'e')]
```

You could also accumulate all the results into a list as the search proceeds.

Answer (score 3):

Make the recursive function return a list of all concatenations.

I.e., you make a function `concatenations`, with a string and a set as input. This function returns a list of all concatenations of items from the set that fit the string.

Then you can define `concatenations` recursively in terms of itself:

- *(end condition)* if the string is empty, then any set satisfies the condition, so return a list with a single, empty, concatenation.

  ```
  concatenations("", any set) = [[]]   # single empty concatenation
  ```
- *(recursive call)* otherwise, the set of concatenations of the elements of the set that make up the string can be defined as the concatenation of an element X of the set with all concatenations of the string with X removed (from the start) and the set with X removed, for all X with which the string starts.

  ```
  concatenations(s, set) =
    sum([[[x] + y for y in concatenations(s[len(x):], set - x))]
         for x in set if s.startswith(x)], [])
  ```

(code is half python, half math; I hope this gives enough hints :p)

Answer (score 0):

The way without using a tree is to just try it by going over all possible permutations, but as soon as you add any intelligence to this randomness, I have the impression you'd go back to a tree like structure again.

That said, a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) structure sounds fit for that. Two popular Python implementations are available for implementing this, [trie](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/trie) and [PyTrie](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyTrie).